# Does posting questions on weekends reduce the chance of getting an answer?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, unanswered-questions

Or point me to some statistics page that could help me answer my own question.

Does posting questions on weekends reduce the chance of getting an answer? It obviously doesn't count if the answers are fewer because the questions are fewer.

Comment: @rene not a duplicate. The other one does not even mention weekends. Same general idea, but different question IMO.

Comment: No. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329143/4751173 (that's about views, but I expect the answers follow a similar pattern)

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard: Dupe mentions "weekday", which is certainly enough to qualify, and one of the answers gives a graph by weekday including weekends

Comment: @NathanTuggy Between us nitpickers, "weekday" being "certainly enough to qualify" is an overstatement.

Comment: @argle: Normally that would be true, absent any particular context, but a question that asks "what's the best weekday to ask on" to *mean* "what day of the week, excluding weekends, is best to ask on" would be quite unnatural, and would need some special verbiage to make quite clear that no, they really do not intend to include weekends at all for some particular reason. (And in fact the answer given that satisfies that particular aspect does include weekends in its graph.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy Are you being serious? I am genuinely unable to tell.

Comment: @argle: Perfectly serious. Why, exactly, would anyone need to ask "what day, M-F, should I ask a question on SE, but S/S are no good"? If they have a problem at work, but can afford to wait a day or three to hit the high spot in answering patterns, surely it is not at all difficult for them to wait until the weekend if necessary. And if they can't wait, then they shouldn't be wasting time asking about the best times at all. So the other question does not seem to have been asked (nor was it answered) under the M-F only assumption.